# node.js installation of express isn't working

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm trying to learn Node.js and am wanting to add express to it's library.

i'm on a 2020 macbook pro with i& core (i think some said 1M is a little different)

i'm able to use node.js. but other then downloading node.js i can't update anything else. i've tried:

adding express: $ npm install express --save
NPM error code EACCES permission denied.

adding  'nvm' : curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash
NPM error code EACCES permission denied.

then found online that some need to download the express generator, tried this:
sudo npm install -g express-generator.
which indicated 10 packages were added, 11 were oddited. with 4 vulnerabilities.
then trying its reccomendation of npm audit fix --force gave an error of ENOLOCK.

I've updated to the newest Node.js. and have been dealing with this issue over an hour.

thank you

Comment: ...did you run `npm init` in a directory to create a package.json?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling node and reinstalling it via nvm?

Comment: @eol that might be it but $10 says OP is trying to npm install --save stuff in a directory that's protected and/or doesn't have a package.json

Comment: @JaredSmith, you got me, that and the code on there site places a "$" at the beginning of the command. and it kept giving me an error. but thank you for the quick response

Comment: @DaltonSimeone the dollar sign is there because it's the standard shell prompt. Most developers would implicitly understand that it's not part of the command.